# Como definir um Fragment de tela inicial para aplicativo Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Criei um APP com um menu gaveta, aquele menu `drawable` que aparece como template na hora de criar um projeto no Android Studio. Consegui criar os `fragments` e relacionar com o menu, está funcionando beleza, meu problema é que não consigo definir meu `fragment` "home" como inicial, por exemplo, ao abrir o aplicativo queria que fosse carregado esse `fragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir um `fragment` inicial, basta usar o `FragmentTransaction` em seu `onCreate()`. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
ExemploFragment fragment = new ExemploFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_exemplo, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```